# Changing element depending on order in the tree

Tags: javascript, html

I have several lists of radio-options(class radio-options) and prices(class option-price). I need to show the price that is currently selected, by "show" i mean make it visible (have no no-display)

HTML structure is the following:

list 1:

```
<div class="radio-options" id="options-9-list">
        <input class="radio  name="options[9]" id="options_9_2" value="35" checked="" type="radio"><label class="radio-options__label" for="options_9_2">1 hour</label>
        <input class="radio  name="options[9]" id="options_9_3" value="36" type="radio"><label class="radio-options__label" for="options_9_3">2 hours</label>
        <input class="radio  name="options[9]" id="options_9_4" value="37" type="radio"><label class="radio-options__label" for="options_9_4">3 hours</label>
</div>


<dl class="option-price">
    <dt class="tour-1">
    <dt class="tour-2 no-display">
    <dt class="tour-3 no-display">
</dl>
```

list 2:

```
<div class="radio-options" id="options-10-list">
        <input class="radio  name="options[10]" id="options_10_2" value="45" checked="" type="radio"><label class="radio-options__label" for="options_10_2">1 hour</label>
        <input class="radio  name="options[10]" id="options_10_3" value="46" type="radio"><label class="radio-options__label" for="options_10_3">2 hours</label>
        <input class="radio  name="options[10]" id="options_10_4" value="47" type="radio"><label class="radio-options__label" for="options_10_4">3 hours</label>
        <input class="radio  name="options[10]" id="options_10_5" value="48" type="radio"><label class="radio-options__label" for="options_10_5">4 hours</label>
</div>


<dl class="option-price">
    <dt class="tour-4">
    <dt class="tour-8 no-display">
    <dt class="tour-11 no-display">
    <dt class="tour-14 no-display">
</dl>
```

The pattern is the following, the 1st button in radio-options must show 1st price in option-price, 2nd button in radio-options must show 2nd price in option-price, etc...

How can i write 1 function to cover all lists like this? Without need to include particular option IDs/class (like options_9_2, tour-1, etc)

p.s Lists are located on different pages (it's 1 list per page).

Comment: I'm hoping that the lack of closing quotes on the `<input>` class attributes are typos?

Comment: @RandyCasburn - that's what we have now. Thank you for pointing it out.